# My Featured Image option suddenly disappeared

Tags: bug

I saw so many fixes for this, but not working.
I actually created a post with featured image, but after that, the option disappeared.
Not in the screen Elements.
Not in the post settings.
Please help me[image]

Comment: Did u install any new theme or plugin?